# android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, uri

I am having this problem when trying to share single or multiple files with my app. When I select a single file and tap share icon and choose my application, i get the uri of the file, whereas when i select multiple files, i get an Arraylist of uri. Below is my code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // AuthDetails.initiate(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdfupload);

    ArrayList<String> fileUriList= (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Log.e("urilist", fileUriList.toString());


    init();

    btCancel.setOnClickListener(cancelUploadListener);
    btUploadPDF.setOnClickListener(uploadPdfListener);
}
```

I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
                                                                at com.example.newActivity.activities.PDFUploadActivity.onCreate(PDFUploadActivity.java:44)
```

Is there a way to manage both single selection and multiple selection scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ArrayList<Uri> fileUriList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
Log.e("urilist", fileUriList.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I came around with a similar issue and here is what you can do.

```
    String action = getIntent().getAction();
    intent = new Intent(this, MyActivityToBeOpen.class);
    if (action == null) {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case Intent.ACTION_SEND:
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (Parcelable) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
            break;

        case Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE:
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
            break;
    }
```